# Reading csv string into bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

The following function uses `awk` to convert a csv line to multiple lines. I then can assign the output to an array to be able to access the fields.

```
function csv_to_lines() {
echo $@ | awk '
BEGIN {FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")";}
{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {printf("%s\n", $i)}}'
}

line='A,B,"C,D",E'
arr=($(csv_to_lines $line))

printf '%s,' "${arr[@]}"
```

However, this doesn't work for empty fields. For example:

```
line='A,,,,,"C,D",E'
arr=($(csv_to_lines $line))

printf '%s,' "${arr[@]}"
```

Outputs

```
A,"C,D",E,
```

But I expected

```
A,,,,,"C,D",E,
```

Evidently, all empty lines are ignored when assigning to the array. How do I create an array that keeps the empty lines?

Comment: In awk `printf("%s\n", $i)` = `print $i`. You also have a few shell errors in your script that copy/pasting it into http://shellcheck.net would tell you about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current code:

```
$ line='A,,,,,"C,D",E'
$ csv_to_lines $line
A




"C,D"
E
```

Looking at the actual characters generated we see:

```
$ csv_to_lines $line | od -c
0000000   A  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n   "   C   ,   D   "  \n   E  \n
0000016
```

As is the `arr=(...)` is going to split this data on white space and store the printable characters in the array, effectively doing the same as:

```
$ arr=(A
"C,D"
E)
$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="A" [1]="C,D" [2]="E")

$ printf '%s,' "${arr[@]}"
A,"C,D",E,
```

A couple ideas for storing the 'blank lines' in the array:

Use `mapfile` to read each *line* into the array, eg:

```
$ mapfile -t arr < <(csv_to_lines $line)
$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="A" [1]="" [2]="" [3]="" [4]="" [5]="\"C,D\"" [6]="E")
```

Or have `awk` use something other than `\n` as a delimiter, then define a custom `IFS` to parse the function results into the array, eg:

```
$ function csv_to_lines() { echo $@ | awk '
BEGIN {FPAT = "([^,]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")";}
{for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {printf("%s|", $i)}}'; }

$ csv_to_lines $line
A|||||"C,D"|E|

$ IFS='|' arr=($(csv_to_lines $line))
$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="A" [1]="" [2]="" [3]="" [4]="" [5]="\"C,D\"" [6]="E")
```

Both of these lead to:

```
$ printf '%s,' "${arr[@]}"
A,,,,,"C,D",E,
```

Comment: `mapfile` solution is perfect. Using a character like `|` would run into issues if the csv has `|` in one of the fields.